# Taking Floating Point Number as String and Performing Aritmetic in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have the following Bash code, which runs a C++ binary (`./code`) and stores the result:

```
#!/bin/bash

output=$(./code /);

read -ra arr -d '' <<<"$output" 
value=${arr[-1]}
sum=$value+1.034
echo $sum
```

I want it to be able to take the value of the variable `sum`, which is a number less than zero, ie `0.01357` and be able to add another floating point number to it, before outputting the result to the screen.

So the result should be 1.04757, but the output I am currently getting is:

```
0.01357+1.034
```

Comment: Bash doesn't support floating point math, plus you're not doing the right thing for math in bash anyways. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360324/addition-of-two-floating-point-numbers-using-shell-script for ways to get around the lack (they generally involve using `bc` or `awk` or another program)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floating point arithmetics. You need another program doing the math for you.
Here are three examples using `bc`, `awk` or GNU `datamash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -ra arr -d '' <<<"$(./code /)" 

# bc
printf '%s + %s\n' "${arr[-1]}"  "1.034" | bc

# or awk
#awk -v val="${arr[-1]}" 'BEGIN{print val + 1.034}'

# or datamash
#datamash sum 1 <<<$(printf '%s\n' "${arr[-1]}" "1.034")
```

Comment: This is quite helpful. Using awk is working for me. I'm curious, if I just wanted to store the result of the sum in a variable, for later use, how would I do that?

Comment: You can use a command substitution: `sum=$(awk -v val="${arr[-1]}" 'BEGIN{print val + 1.034}')`

Comment: One more question. What if I had two bash variables that I wanted to add together with awk?

Comment: Assign two variables to `awk` with the `-v` option, e.g. 
`one="0.5"; two="1.1"; sum=$(awk -v var1="$one" -v var2="$two" 'BEGIN{print var1 + var2}')` or you could `echo` the values and use a pipe like `sum=$(echo "0.5;1.1" | awk -F';' '{ print $1 + $2 }')`